# Combining Multiple Rectangles in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection, polygons

I am making a game, and I want to make several levels, but each would have separate areas to collide with, so to simplify this task i want to use something other than a rectangle in order to make many different platforms and walls, without out needing to repeat the detection code.

In other words, is there a way to combine two or more rectangles so that they can be treated as one using Rectangle2D.intersects(Rectangle2D)?
Or is there another workaround for this that I don't know about?

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what result you expect? Are you trying to find where two or more rectangles intersect? The bounding box of two or more rectangles? Something else?

Comment: All known implementing classes of `java.awt.Shape` have the required `contains()` and `intersects()` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html). It is an implementation of the [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, which will provide the `intersects()` and `contains()` methods mentioned by @trashgod in the comments above.

To add a part of the level in, such as an instance of `Rectangle2D`, check out the `append()` method.

Hopefully this is will help out.